# channel.recv didn't return prompt back even after command is completed. 'while True' loop didn't break

Tags: python, paramiko

channel.recv didn't return prompt back even after command is completed. 'while True' loop didn't break.

I am using paramiko to login a server with user 'xyz' and then 'su -' using paramiko channel.

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    ssh.connect(hostname, username='xyz', password=list_pass(hostname, 'xyz'))

    command = 'puppet agent -t --no-use_cached_catalog ; echo COMMAND_COMPLETED'

    channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
    channel.send("su -\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    channel.send(list_pass(hostname, 'root') + "\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    channel.send(command + '\n')
    time.sleep(5)

    while True:
        if channel.recv:
            time.sleep(1)
            print(channel.recv(1024).decode())
            if "COMMAND_COMPLETED" in channel.recv(1024).decode():
                break
        else:
            continue

    channel.close()
    ssh.close()

except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
    print("Authentication failed")
except socket.gaierror:
    print(f"Can't connect to {hostname}. Verify if server exists and it's up.")
```

This code went to infinite loop. Command still running.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZUMI.png)

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by *"channel.recv didn't return prompt back"*. I see the prompt in your screenshot. It should also be nice if you post the terminal output (also) as a text. + See [Allowing automatic command execution as root on Linux using SSH](https://superuser.com/q/1481318/213663).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below code and it worked.

```
channel.send(command + '\n')
time.sleep(5)
# Create a new receive buffer
receive_buffer = ""

while not receive_buffer.endswith("# ") or receive_buffer.endswith("$ "):
    '''
    'root' user prompt ends with '# '.
    'non-root' user prompt end with '$ '.
    '''
    receive_buffer += channel.recv(9999).decode()

print(receive_buffer)
channel.close()
ssh.close()
```